# UDK "Error, Unrecognized member 'FocalPoint' in class ..."

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I'm porting a UT3 game to [UDK](http://www.udk.com/).

It uses a large code library and I'm getting this compiler error:

> C:\UDK\UDK-2010-03\Development\Src\FixIt\Classes\ZController_FireWeapon.uc(129) : Error, Unrecognized member 'FocalPoint' in class 'ZController'

ZController extends UTBot. This is the referenced line:

```
Agent.FocalPoint = ObjectOfAttention.Location;
```

(Agent is of type ZController)

**What happened to FocalPoint?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! The line above my FocalPoint line involved setting `Agent.Focus`; so I traced the line of `UTBot -> UDKBot -> AIController -> Controller` and finally the Controller class has a Focus member:

```
var BasedPosition FocalPosition; // position controlled pawn is looking at
var Actor         Focus;         // actor being looked at
```

So, `FocalPoint` was renamed to `FocalPosition`.

It's not over yet! Apparently FocalPoint used to be a vector and now FocalPosition is a BasedPosition. So my code still didn't work because it was trying to assign a vector to a BasedPosition; the compiler complained with `Error, Type mismatch in '='`. BasedPosition is a struct in Actor and has a vector member `Position`, so I will assume that's the correct variable to assign to.

I changed my line of code from

```
Agent.FocalPoint = ObjectOfAttention.Location;
```

to

```
Agent.FocalPosition.Position = ObjectOfAttention.Location;
```

I haven't tested it (still working on other compiler errors) but it compiles fine now. Hopefully this is the correct solution.